# How to restart this statement after the dice is rolled?

Tags: python, restart

How can I restart this statement after the dice is rolled (after answer "m" was typed)?

```
import numpy as np

print"Type 'm' to roll a dice."

answer = raw_input("> ")
if answer == "m":
    print(np.random.randint(1, 7))
else:
    print"Error"
```

Comment: You may want to look into Python's control structures, cf. e.g. https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Introduction/ControlStructures.html

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it around `while` statement like this:

```
import numpy as np

while True:
  print "Type 'm' to roll a dice."
  answer = raw_input("> ")
  if answer == "m":
    print(np.random.randint(1, 7))
  else:
    print"Error"
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stop = False

while stop == False:
    answer = raw_input("> ")
    if answer == "m":
        print(np.random.randint(1, 7))
    else:
        print"Error"
        stop = True
```

Answer (score 1):

In my answer I assumed you wanted to terminate the program when the user didn't type a "m", but in case you want to keep in running, the while block is enough

```
while True:
    answer = raw_input("> ")
        if answer == "m":
            print(np.random.randint(1, 7))
        else:
            print"Error"
            exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate everything in a while loop, as follows:

```
while True:
    answer = raw_input("Type 'm' to roll a dice: \n> ")
    if answer == "m":
        print(np.random.randint(1, 7))
    else:
        print"Error"
```

This way, every time the user enters 'm', the np.random call will run. If they enter anything, it will print "Error", and then run the loop again, asking them to enter 'm'.